# Why is mktime unsetting gmtoff ? How to make mktime use the gmtoff field?

Tags: c, datetime, unix-timestamp

I want to get an unix timestamp from a `string` containing a representation of the time of the form `YYYYMMDDThhmmss+TZ`.

For that, I convert the string into a `struct tm` and then use `mktime` to convert it to an unix timestamp.

```
str = "20150228T202832+02";
struct tm time_struct = {0};
strptime(str,"%Y%m%dT%H%M%S%z", &time_struct);
uint64_t timestamp = mktime(&time_struct); /* ignore and unset TZ */
```

It becomes a problem when I use a different time zone than the one I'm in. The `mktime` function ignores and *unset* the `tm_gmtoff` field of the `struct tm`, returning a wrong timestamp (the difference is given by the `string`'s time zone minus my time zone).

- Why is `mktime` ignoring the `tm_gmtoff` field of the `struct tm`?
- Why is `mktime` setting the `tm_gmtoff` field to my current time zone *without modifying accordingly the rest of the `struct tm`* ? (making the `struct tm` *represent a different time*!)

To correct this behavior, I would like to add the difference between my time zone and the time zone of the `string` to the fields of the `struct tm`, before making the call to `mktime`.

- How could I get my current time zone without making a new (useless) `struct tm` ?

Comment: I'd say `mktime` assumes local time per C spec: "The mktime function converts the broken-down time, expressed as **local time**"

Comment: Maybe 1) change local time zone to UTC, 2) call mktime() 3) restore local timezone 4) add `tm_gmtoff` to step 2 result.

Comment: +1 to @chux; GNU C Library even provides `timelocal` as a synonym for `mktime`. I suggest that you adjust your `time_struct` to UTC (using `tm_gmtoff`) and use `timegm`. Another option is to temporarily adjust your `TZ` environment variable while calling `mktime`.

Comment: Check this example [asn1_time_t.c](http://storkhole.cz/software/ikeman/asn1_time_t.c). There is `convert` label at the end of file. That could be what you need. Or [C: Converting struct tm times with timezone to time_t](http://kbyanc.blogspot.com/2007/06/c-converting-struct-tm-times-with.html): solution with `timegm()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a code snippet that responds to my problem. The trick was to use the global variable `timezone`.

```
/*
    Function: timestamp_from_datetime
    Returns the timestamp corresponding to a formated string YYYYMMDDTHHMMSS+TZ

    Parameters:
        datetime - must be non-NULL

    Returns:
        The timestamp associated to datetime
 */
time_t timestamp_from_datetime(const char *datetime)
{
    struct tm time_struct = (struct tm) {0};
    strptime(datetime,"%Y%m%dT%H%M%S%z", &time_struct);
    long int gmtoff = time_struct.tm_gmtoff;
    return mktime(&time_struct) - gmtoff - timezone;
}
```